# ¿Cómo recorrer los elementos de una lista de listas?

Tags: python

¡Hola!

No sé si podréis ayudarme, tengo una lista de listas y me gustaría acceder a todos los elementos de las sublistas pero que continuaran estando divididos. Mi lista podría ser algo parecido a esto:

```
lista=[["PATATA","GARBABANZOS"],["MELOCOTONES","PERAS"],["LECHE","CHOCOLATE","GALLETAS"]]
```

y yo por ejemplo, quiero pasar todas las cadenas a minúsculas, pero que sigan estando dentro de sus listas. Solo consigo pasar los elementos de una lista, no de todas.

```
compra=[]
for x in lista:
    compra.append(x.lower())
compra
```

esto es el resultado que querría:

```
 
compra=[["patata","garbanzos"],["melocotones","peras"],["leche","chocolate","galletas"]]
```

Ojalá podáis ayudarme, ya me he quedado sin ideas y soy algo nuevo en esto...

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar una comprensión de listas dentro de otra comprensión de listas para lograrlo:

```
compra = [[item.lower() for item in items] for items in compra]
```

Que es equivalente a:

```
compra2 = []

for items in compra:
   compra2.append([item.lower() for item in items])

compra = compra2
```

Que a su vez es equivalente a:

```
compra2 = []

# obtenemos cada lista dentro de compra
for items in compra:
   # creamos una lista que contendrá los nuevos items pero en minusculas.
   items2 = []

   # recorremos la lista de items original
   for item in items:
       # agregamos el item a la nueva lista, pero en minusculas
       items2.append(item.lower())

   compra2.append(items2)

compra = compra2
```

Más info sobre las compresiones de lista aquí: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/

Answer (score 2):

Me gustaría aportar una forma recursiva al recorrido de la lista donde además transformara a minúsculas. Esta no es la forma mas eficiente de hacerlo pero podría ser útil en algunos casos.

#### Recorrer una lista y sublistas de forma recursiva modificando elementos

Tenemos la lista con sublistas en mayúsculas.

```
listaMayusculas=[["PATATA","GARBABANZOS"],["MELOCOTONES","PERAS"],["LECHE","CHOCOLATE","GALLETAS"]]


def recorrerLista(lista):
    listaNueva=[]
    for i in lista:
    if isinstance(i,list): # verificamos si es tipo lista
        listaNueva.append(recorrerLista(i)) # entra nuevamente a recorrerLista
    else:
        listaNueva.append(i.lower()) # ingresa elemento de lista en mayúscula
return listaNueva
```

Ahora la función recorrerLista(lista) nos devolverá una **Lista nueva** con todos sus **elementos de la lista original modificados** pero en el mismo orden y dentro de sus sublistas.

```
print("Lista nueva: ", recorrerLista(listaMayusculas))
Lista nueva:  [['patata', 'garbabanzos'], ['melocotones', 'peras'], ['leche', 'chocolate', 'galletas']]
```

En cambio la **Lista Original** se mantiene igual sin modificación:

```
print("Lista original: ", listaMayusculas)
Lista original:  [['PATATA', 'GARBABANZOS'], ['MELOCOTONES', 'PERAS'], ['LECHE', 'CHOCOLATE', 'GALLETAS']]
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Ciertamente. Esta es una buena solución si quieres aplicar la función de manera profunda. Es decir si hay sublistas dentro de sublistas, dentro de...

Comment: Por ejemplo esta es la unica solución dada que funcionaría con algo como `[["hola", ["mundo"]], "color"]`.

Comment: Sin embargo, para una lista de listas de cadenas, todas las soluciones funcionan (al menos al momento de publicar este comentario)

Answer (score 1):

Lo tienes casi, casi. Lo primero, usar nombres significativos para las variables, pues así se entiende mejor que pasa:

```
compra=[]
for sublista in lista:
    nva_sublista = []
    for nombre in sublista:
        nva_sublista.append(nombre.lower())
    compra.append(nva_sublista)
```

Cuando recorres `lista`, lo que obtienes es otra lista (`sublista`).

Con el `for` más interno recorremos la sublista, y ahora si tenemos los nombres que hay que poner en minúsculas. Puesto ya en minúsculas, lo agregamos a la lista de salida `compra`.

#### Demo

```
lista=[["PATATA","GARBABANZOS"],["MELOCOTONES","PERAS"],["LECHE","CHOCOLATE","GALLETAS"]]
compra=[]
for sublista in lista:
    print(sublista)
    nva_sublista = []
    for nombre in sublista:
        nva_sublista.append(nombre.lower())
    compra.append(nva_sublista)

print(compra)
```

produce:

```
[['patata', 'garbabanzos'], ['melocotones', 'peras'], ['leche', 'chocolate', 'galletas']]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `x` es corresponde a las sublistas no a las cadenas de texto.

Podrias hacerlo así:

```
compra=[]
for x in lista:
    compra.append([e.lower() for e in x])
print(compra)
```

o reducirlo:

```
print([list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), t)) for t in lista])
```